# Transfer ForeignKey relationship when copying entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, primary-key, foreign-key-relationship

I have two entities (`MediaFileDescriptor` and `TransformationTest`) with foreign-key relationships to two different subsets of another entity (`MediaFileMetaData`) collection.

So, a subset of my `MediaFileMetaData` collection is linked to a `MediaFileDescriptor` and another subset of  my `MediaFileMetaData` collection is linked to `TransformationTest`.

**TransformationTest.cs:**

```
public class TransformationTest : IEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set;
    public virtual ICollection<MediaFileMetaData> MediaFileMetaDatas { get; set; }

    // some more properties (removed for readability)
 }
```

**MediaFileDescriptor.cs:**

```
public class MediaFileDescriptor : IEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<MediaFileMetaData> MediaFileMetaDatas { get; set; }

    // some more properties (removed for readability)
}
```

**MediaFileMetaData.cs:**

```
public class MediaFileMetaData : IEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int TransformationTestId { get; set; }
    public virtual TransformationTest TransformationTest { get; set; }

    public int MediaFileDescriptorId { get; set; }
    public virtual MediaFileDescriptor MediaFileDescriptor { get; set; }

    // some more properties (removed for readability) 
}
```

I am now creating copies of these entities. After copying `TransformationTest` and the linked `MediaFileMetaData`, I want to create a copy of the `MediaFileDescriptor`. I don't want to replicate the `MediaFileMetaData` again, but want to link the entities that I just replicated in the previous step with my new copy of `MediaFileDescriptor`. But since my new `MediaFileDescriptor` has a new `id`, the copied `MediaFileMetaData`s are referencing to the original `MediaFileDescriptor`.

So, my problem is: How can I tell the entity framework which subset of my `MediaFileMetaData` collection (e.g. all entities with the old `MediaFileDescriptor.Id`) are linked to my new `MediaFileDescriptor`?

Here are my relationship specifications (not sure whats the correct name):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TransformationTest>()
    .HasMany<MediaFileMetaData>(c => c.MediaFileMetaDatas)
    .WithRequired(c => c.TransformationTest)
    .HasForeignKey(c => c.TransformationTestId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

modelBuilder.Entity<MediaFileDescriptor>()
    .HasMany<MediaFileMetaData>(c => c.MediaFileMetaDatas)
    .WithRequired(c => c.MediaFileDescriptor)
    .HasForeignKey(c => c.MediaFileDescriptorId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

This is my (not working) code:

```
var newTests = source.TransformationTests.Select(
    c => new TransformationTest
        {
            // replicating other properties
            MediaFileMetaDatas = c.MediaFileMetaDatas.Select(m => new MediaFileMetaData { Data = m.Data }).ToList()
        });

var newFileDescriptors = source.MediaFileDescriptors.Select(
    c => new MediaFileDescriptor
        {
            // replicating other properties
            MediaFileMetaDatas =  // what should go here?
        });
```

Unfortunately me program is to complex to give a minimal working example ...

Answer (score 0):

How about going the other way and creating the new `MediaFileDescriptor` when linking the new `MediaFileMetaData`collection to the `TransformationTest`?

```
var newTests = source.TransformationTests.Select(
    c => new TransformationTest
        {
            // replicating other properties
            MediaFileMetaDatas = c.MediaFileMetaDatas.Select(m => new MediaFileMetaData {
                Data = m.Data,
                MediaFileDescriptor = new MediaFileDescriptor {
                    // copy data from existing descriptor
                }
            }).ToList()
        });
```

If you require the newly created descriptors you can access them like so:

```
var newFileDescriptors = source.TransformationTests.SelectMany(
    c => c.MediaFileMetaDatas.Select(m => m.MediaFileDescriptor));
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response. We decided to refactor our code to avoid this problem. The whole structure was kind of messed up and kept causing problems. But thank you for your effort!